# From xml folder data to pandas data frame

Tags: python, xml, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-datareader

Here is my code (I actually copied a similar answer from another question) however I am getting a response of :    *No such file or directory: '9320_info.xml'*

Background:I have a file saved in my computer with all the files I want to extract 
[please see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ZMp.png)

My code is:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
import xmltodict

folder_data = 'C:/Users/M00220/Downloads/Spain Hydro/River/xml/'

with open('9320_info.xml', 'r') as f:
data = xmltodict.parse(f.read())['ETRS89 X']['ETRS89 Y']['Huso']

 data_pd = {'X': [data['ETRS89 X']],
            'Y': [data['ETRS89 Y']],
            'Num': [data['Huso']]}

 df = pd.DataFrame(data_pd)
     print(df)
```

So basically what I am trying to do is covert all the xxxx_info.xml to pandas data frame, more specifically those three columns named above. However, it doesnt even recognize the data that is data that is in the folder saved on my computer.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Much appreciated

Comment: You do not use folder_data. Try "folder_data = 'C:/Users/M00220/Downloads/Spain Hydro/River/xml/9320_info.xml' ; with open(folder_data, ...